# Calling View.getTop() in Robolectric always returns 0

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to verify the position of a View on screen but View.getTop or View.getLocationOnScreen() will always return 0.

View.getHeight() is greater than 0 and appears to be correct.

Is this a limitation of Robolectric or is there something I need to setup?

Comment: what device are you testing on?

Comment: Is view attached to the window? I mean view added to activity and activity is already resumed?